# How to use use cytoscape.js in combination with vue.js dynamic component's keep-alive?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, cytoscape.js

I am trying to build a single page application using Vue.js 2.0. The application is supposed to feature multiple modes of operation, which I wanted to implement using Vue.js [dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components). Since the state of each mode should be preserved while switching between them, I decided to use the [keep-alive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive) feature that Vue.js provides. One of the modes is supposed to be a network view created by using Cytoscape.js .

And here comes my problem. The network is initialized correctly when I switch the first time to it, but after switching back and forth, the network view freezes. keep-alive works properly (as far as I understand it) and brings back both the Cytoscape instance and the proper HTML section. Somehow, the connection between the Cytoscape instance and the HTML sections seems to be lost, although I don't understand how and why.

Here is an example code.

```js
//sample data for network
var testElements = [
    { data: {id: 'a'} },
    { data: {id: 'b'} },
    { data: {
        id: 'ab',
        source: 'a',
        target: 'b' 
        }
    }
];
    
//Vue components
Vue.component('otherView', {
    template: '<div>This is another mode</div>'
});

Vue.component('network', {
    template: '<div id="container" class="cy"></div>',
    mounted: function () {
        cy1 = cytoscape({
            container: document.getElementById("container"),
            elements: testElements
        });
    }
});

//Vue dynamic component
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#dynamic",
    data: {
        currentView: 'otherView'
    }
});
```

```css
.cy {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/master/dist/cytoscape.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="dynamic" >
    <div id="selectorButton">
        <button id="button1" @click="currentView='otherView'">Other view</button>
        <button id="button2" @click="currentView='network'">Network</button>
    </div>

    <keep-alive>
        <component :is="currentView"></component>
    </keep-alive>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove a Cytoscape instance, you've destroyed it.  Either make sure that Vue doesn't destroy your DOM elements or create a new Cytoscape instance each time from JSON: http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.json

Comment: So, in conclusion, it just doesn't work? Option 1 ("Either make sure that Vue doesn't destroy your DOM elements") makes in my case the use of Vue.js and dynamic components obsolet, and option 2 ("or create a new Cytoscape instance each time from JSON") is not feasable due to long runtime.

As for my case, I will go with option 1 and hide the ctoscape instance with `style='display: none;'` when I don't need it.

Comment: The entire state of the graph is serialisable via json.  In terms of state, there's generally no difference between creating a new instance with the same json as keeping an old one.

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand your problem completely , but you can try shifting code you have written in **network** component's mounted oroperty to activated property as follows

```
    Vue.component('network', {
        template: '<div id="container" class="cy"></div>',
        activated: function () {
            if(initial state){
                cy1 = cytoscape({
                    container: document.getElementById("container"),
                    elements: testElements
                });
            }

        }
    });
```

This may help because when a cmponent is **kept-alive** the mounted hook is called only once when first time enter you the component, its not called again on subsequent entering whereas activated hook is called everytime you enter the component when **kept-alive**

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Although you are right that this approach would prevent the network view from freezing, the main point of using **keep-alive** is to preserve the state of the component during switching. If I use the **activated** hook, this functionality is lost and the network is reloaded to its initial state every time I access the component. This is (for this example) basically the same as discarding the **keep-alive** tag.

Comment: @PhJ then try using an if statement in the activated hook which gets executed only if state has been changed else remain the same

Comment: I am sorry but now I am confused. As far as I understand your suggestion, on the one hand the network would get re-initialized every time it has been changed (for example the selection of a node), which is something I don't want as I want to preseve the changes (therefore I try to use the **keep-alive** feature). On the other hand the network would not be re-initialized if it was not changed (which is good) but then I still have the problem that the Cytoscape instance somehow breaks (best shown by testing whether node selection or drag and drop still works).

Comment: @PhJ i have never worked on cytoscape, so bit confused on how the instance works

Comment: Me too. What I see on the surface is that there exists a cytoscape object (`cy1` in my example) which is connected to a HTML element (`<div id="container" class="cy"></div>`). I also don't understand how this connection works. After retrieving both the cytoscape object and the HTML element unchanged after switching back and forth with **keep-alive** activated, this connection seems to be lost. How or why this is happening, I have no idea.

Comment: @PhJ sorry i tried but could not help you... i think the answer could be found if we knew how the connection works.... i'll check online and comeback to you if i solve it out